# I'm not obsessed with this treasure, I promise!

Tags: riddle, rhyme

So, yesterday I received a treasure, can you guess what it is?

> For me to receive this treasure, I had to wait for quite some time,
> A time I did pass with leisure, many obstacles I had to climb.
>
> Never ceasing, I continued day by day.
> Always piecing, many foes I did slay.
>
> To receive a prize, one most precious indeed.
> I widened my eyes, until I did succeed.
>
> Can you tell me what I've gotten? It's the first of it's kind I've received.

Comment: You always have an acronym in your riddles! What are you, a **fanatic**? :D

Comment: @user477343, It's kind of my calling card.

Comment: I would like to see if you can make **JoeYouKnow** be one of your calling cards :P

Comment: @user477343, What? You don't like the hyphens?

Comment: *Ahem* **Joe-You-Know** xD

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Did you get

> A gold badge on PSE?

For me to receive this treasure, I had to wait for quite some time,
A time I did pass with leisure, many obstacles I had to climb.

> Sure enough, you have had to answer and ask a lot of questions for quite some time, 100 days to be specific, before you received this!

Never ceasing, I continued day by day.
Always piecing, many foes I did slay.

> Yes, we have been seeing your challenging puzzles as well as piecing together your answers beating foes like @El-Guest :P

To receive a prize, one most precious indeed.

> Gold badge is definitely the highest and a precious badge indeed!

I widened my eyes, until I did succeed.

> I'm guessing you learnt a lot while asking and answering questions!

I only just saw @El-Guest's part of the answer that says:

> FANATIC. We know you are a puzzling fanatic now!
>  And I just saw that the badge you received is FANATIC! :)

And Congratulations! :D

Comment: Dang it, this is 100% it. Great find! (And congrats, Joe-You-Know!) :D

Comment: Would you be able to expound on your answer? This is 100% correct by the way! :D

Comment: Excellent edit. Thanks! I always give 24 hours before accepting answers, but I'll be sure to accept it then!

Answer (score 2):

Did you get

> The One Ring, from LOTR?

For me to receive this treasure, I had to wait for quite some time,

> It was buried in the river Anduin for a long time; after that Gollum had it for a long time; after that Bilbo had it for a long time before it finally got to Frodo.

A time I did pass with leisure, many obstacles I had to climb.

> Living in the shire was very leisurely before Bilbo gave Frodo the Ring; after that he had to climb the Misty Mountains, then Cirith Ungol, then Mount Doom.

Never ceasing, I continued day by day.

> He kept on trekking towards Mt. Doom (for the most part without stopping).

Always piecing, many foes I did slay.

> Lots of killing

To receive a prize, one most precious indeed.

> The Precious!

I widened my eyes, until I did succeed.

> Gollum's eyes were unnaturally wide by the time he meets Frodo.

Can you tell me what I've gotten? It's the first of it's kind I've received.

> It's the One Ring?

Hidden clue:

> The acronym FANATIC, which is what the Ring turns people into.

Comment: I see that you've gotten the jump on it today. But no, the precious is not mine...

Comment: Ooh I thought I had it for sure! I'll keep thinking...

Comment: The riddle was definitely set up to make us believe it's this. It's what I really love about this riddle. Amazing work, joe!

Comment: @Cashbee, Actually, I wasn't thinking of this at all. This just happened to fit well out of sheer coincidence... (Maybe subconsciously I built it this way?  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯)

Comment: Oh, let me remove my upvote then.. jk :) While reading i was waiting for the keyword 'precious' to show up. When it did, i was sure you did it intentionally as red herring. I had this answer in mind since i read the title actually

Answer (score 1):

Is the treasure

> a Chest from the video game Bayonetta, found by finding an Umbra Witch's final resting place?

For me to receive this treasure, I had to wait for quite some time,

> It takes a lot of time to find each Chest.

A time I did pass with leisure, many obstacles I had to climb.

> Playing the video game is considered leisure, although there are many obstacles.

Never ceasing, I continued day by day.

> You could play it every day.

Always piecing, many foes I did slay.

> Bayonetta is a "hack-and-slash" game.

To receive a prize, one most precious indeed.

> The Chests are extremely precious in the game.

I widened my eyes, until I did succeed.

> Maybe this is a reference to the state of one's vision after playing for so long?

Can you tell me what I've gotten? It's the first of it's kind I've received.

> It could be the first chest, or the first Silver award you've received?

The secret hint

> FANATIC could be used to describe the achievement TREASURE FANATIC, which is earned once all of the Chests/final resting places have been found.

Comment: No, this isn't it. It's not an answer you need the trivia or video game tag for. Besides, I haven't played this game (Not really my style, honestly).

Comment: That's fair enough, I need to pay more attention to the tags haha. I just googled Treasure Fanatic tbh, I've never played this either!