# What's This Shiny New Thing?

Tags: riddle, word

**Edit** :

As the riddle has already been solved, I will state the source of inspiration of this riddle, which is [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/70937/im-not-obsessed-with-this-treasure-i-promise) by @[Joe-You-Know](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/48593/joe-you-know)

Here goes :

> A shiny one this is
>
> Finally getting this after such a long time dreaming of it
>
> It wasn't a gift from my friends nor is it from my parents
>
> You could say it was like winning one of those competitions
>
> Although I didn't get first place, it still felt amazing
>
> Now all I have to do is reach higher than this one
>
> But I know it will be much harder

Comment: I didn't get my first silver badge that long ago...

Comment: Hmmm, maybe you should make a riddle too about a silver badge lol :D

Comment: The mystery of the stolen silver badge

Comment: @Duck Ooo that would be a nice title, but what would it even be a about??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you get

> A silver badge on PSE? Congratulations :)

A shiny one this is

> Shiny silver

Finally getting this after such a long time dreaming of it

> I'll bet

It wasn't a gift from my friends nor is it from my parents

> Yup, it was from PSE

You could say it was like winning one of those competitions

> Puzzling is not so easy! You did beat a lot of other puzzlers to come so far

Although I didn't get first place, it still felt amazing

> Waiting to get a gold badge

Now all I have to do is reach higher than this one

> Keep going and you'll reach gold

But I know it will be much harder

> Yup, gold badges are rare ones!

Note:

> Please don't stop, we love your puzzles, and upvotes ;) !

Comment: Ah dang it, you're right. Will accept tomorrow and btw, reached my daily voting limit so will upvote tomorrow too :D

Comment: I just realized that you've answered this type of question before, haven't you XD

Comment: Haha yeah! Which is why it hit me as soon as I read the question. Also (V'z jnvgvatgb erprvir n fvyire onqtr gbzbeebj sbe ivfvgvat guvf fvgr rirelqnl sbe 30 qnlf, fb zl zvaq jnf naljnl ehaavat va gung qverpgvba) :P

Comment: Oh, congrats! Hope u get a gold one soon :D

Comment: OK, will immediately answer when u post it XD

Answer (score 0):

Is it(guess)

> A Coin?
> Maybe you found it on the street
> You dreamt of a coin as a child

Comment: Umm, nice answer but how does that relate the winning of competitions (4th line) ?